empty screen appears in react native



home.layout.jsx:
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import SVGWave from '../component/SVGWave';
import { useNavigation } from '../context/NavigationContext';
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  cardContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 165,
  },
  card: {
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#1a8739",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "white",
    elevation: 10,
    borderRadius: 18,
  },
  cardText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "white",
  },
  svgCurve: {
    width: width,
  },
});

export const Home = () => {

  const { navigateTo } = useNavigation()
  const menuItems = [
    { label: "Teachers", icon: "graduation-cap", screen: "Teachers" },
    { label: "Courses", icon: "book", screen: "Courses" },
    { label: "Contact Us", icon: "phone", screen: "Contact" },
    { label: "Settings", icon: "cog", screen: "Settings" }
  ];

  const handleCardPress = (screen) => {
    navigateTo(screen);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SVGWave customStyles={styles.svgCurve} />
      <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
        {menuItems.map(({ label, icon, screen }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={label}
            style={styles.card}
            onPress={() => handleCardPress(screen)}
          >
            <Icon name={icon} size={30} color="white" />
            <Text style={styles.cardText}>{label}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;

layout.controller.js:
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { Home } from '../layouts/home.layout';
import { Profile } from '../layouts/profile.layout';
import { Timetable } from '../layouts/timetable.layout';
import { useNavigation } from '../context/NavigationContext';
import { Teachers } from '../layouts/teachers.layout';
import { Courses } from '../layouts/courses.layout';
import { Contact } from '../layouts/contact.layout';
import { Settings } from '../layouts/settings.layout';

export const LayoutController = () => {
  const { currentPage } = useNavigation();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      {currentPage === 'home' && <Home />}
      {currentPage === 'profile' && <Profile />}
      {currentPage === 'timetable' && <Timetable />}
      {currentPage === 'teachers' && <Teachers />}
      {currentPage === 'courses' && <Courses />}
      {currentPage === 'contact' && <Contact />}
      {currentPage === 'settings' && <Settings />}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

navigationcontext.js:
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

export const NavigationContext = createContext();

export const useNavigation = () => {
  const context = useContext(NavigationContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useNavigation must be used within a NavigationProvider");
  }
  return context;
};

export const NavigationProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState("home");

  const navigateTo = (page) => {
    console.log("Navigating to:", page);
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };
  
  return (
    <NavigationContext.Provider value={{ currentPage, navigateTo }}>
      {children}
    </NavigationContext.Provider>
  );
};

the blank screen appears when clicked on home.layout.jsx screens. what is the issue? the homescreens appear empty  when i clicked on it. i didnt understand what the issue is

Try to add 100% for width and heightcontainer:{width: "100%", height: "100%"}

You need add flex: 1 in
<SafeAreaView>
inside layout.controller.js file
